# Text will not appear on the screen in pygame

Tags: python, text, pygame, pygame-surface

This is the code i have used to try add text to the screen

```
font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 20)

TextX = 700
TextY = 100

def showText(x,y):
    text = font.render("random text", True, (255,0,0))
    screen.blit(text, (x,y))

# Game Loop
running = True
while running:
    showText(TextX,TextY)
```

[I am trying to add the writing in the space on the right, in a column preferable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDJ7Y.png)
Can anyone tell me why the code is not allowing me to blit the text onto the screen and how i should change the code to allow it to blit more text onto the screen.

Comment: Looking at the image, im assuming that you do have a `pygame.display.update()`. The font would raise an error if it couldn't find it so probably not that. Make sure your blitting it after you fill the screen. the code should work

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the display with `pygame.display.update()`.  To write text in a column, you can call your function in a loop.  Here's an updated version of your loop that prints the text repeatedly in a column:

```py
while running:
    window_height = pygame.display.get_surface().get_size()[1]
    for TextY in range(100, window_height, 100):
        showText(TextX,TextY)
    pygame.display.update()
```